# Label positioning in D365 UCI is inconsistent

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I've noticed that in some screens of a Dynamics 365 (D365) UCI application there are times where the label is found to the left or above the field.  Obvious when looking at the Contact entity (above) and any other (to the left).

It is taking up more vertical real estate than I would like, however, cannot find where this is configured.  Is there a property on the form or group that I am missing or is this something new in UCI that cannot yet be toggled?

(See example below)

[image: Difference between labels above and to the left of field in UCI D365]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position of the label text in section properties. Go to Account entity form editor, double click the “Account Information” section, click the “Formatting” tab, change the “Field Label Position” option. Or change it in Contact form section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this response - I think one of the problems is that the page is using the 3 column layout where the middle column is larger.  This forces it (due to the responsive layout) to switch to TOP mode even though it is in SIDE mode.  However, this is definitely the answer.