# Dynamics 365 CE Unified Interface - 2 column layout in section showing one column only

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I have a section with a 2 column layout on the Case form.  This UI setting is showing 2 attributes per row in old Dynmiacs 365 UI -- **Working expected.**

[image]

When I open the same form in the new Unified Client Interface, attributes are showing as 1 column per row. -- **Issue**

[image]

This is using a lot of space in the form.  If I zoom in browser to say, 75%, then new UI is also showing 2 attributes per row, but this shouldn't be the ideal behavior.

[image]

Does anyone else face this issue, and is there a supported workaround to fix it?

Form Customization Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is bit annoying, but this is by design. UCI is built for cross-platform, cross-device, cross-browser compatible responsive layout, similar to bootstrap - which will reflow, self-adjust based on screen size, resolution and available real-estate. [Read this discussion in community](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/368725/unified-interface---form-layout-issue).

You may need to change the layout to two sections instead of two columns in single section, that will suffice your need.

I remember, I was having two forms, ie one for UCI and another for web classic for tackling these cosmetic situations.

SO thread for label related: [Label positioning in D365 UCI is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55688466/7920473)